# Не выполняется setRepeating в AlarmManager

Tags: android, android-alarm-manager

Запуск оформлен через сервис:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("MyService", "--я сервис,запустил Alarm");

        AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intentalarm = new Intent(this, AlarmNotificationMe.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,intentalarm,0);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),1000,pi);    

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
public class AlarmNotificationMe extends BroadcastReceiver {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          Log.d("MyService", "--я сервис,чтото делаю в аларме");
       }
}
}
```

В логах вижу что сервис стартовал "--я сервис,запустил Alarm", о не выполняется "--я сервис,чтото делаю в аларме"

В чем я не прав?

Answer (score 2):

Вроде нужно ресивер в манифесте отметить, внутри тега `application`. В вашем случае примерно так.

```
<receiver
    android:name=".AlarmNotificationMe"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    </receiver>
```